# getting an fatal error exception in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I just followed the tutorial from youtube and I found this error
(before I found this, I change my appname to Chatty by `php artisan`)

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

> 1/1
>   FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 3:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'Chatty' (T_STRING)
>   in HomeController.php line 3

```
<?php

namepsace Chatty\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
  {
      public function index()
      {
        return view('home');
      }
  }
```

Comment: namepsace??? That's wrong :)

Comment: (before I found this, i change my appname to Chatty by php artisan), ok i will try to not change the appname, thanks :D

Comment: Check the spelling of `namespace`.

Comment: wow, its just a typo, thanks @Amarnasan :D :D

Comment: got it @Sougata :D thanks

Comment: guys, I got 1 question, can I convert this laravel web project to native mobile by phonegap ?

Comment: Are not `native` and `phonegap` exclusive words?

Comment: im sorry, exclusive in stackoverflow ? i cant use it ? @Amarnasan.anyway,    i will be using bootstrap as frontend and laravel for the backend.